# Bash readline history previous line before history expansion

Tags: bash, readline, expansion

There are usually the keys Up and Ctrl+P mapped to [previous-history](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC15) Readline command in [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) which moves back in history to previous line with history expanded.

How to move to the previous line before [History expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html)? E.g. to line like

```
!!:gs/20010910/20010911/
```

Comment: I don't know that you can. I think history expansion happens first.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Lines containing history expansions are only stored in history *after* the expansions have been processed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment, it is not possible, because lines containing history expansions are only stored in history *after* the expansions have been processed.

See [feature request](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-12/msg00052.html).